# Sorting order of std::map depending on an input value

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator

I know that you cannot change the ordering of a map once declared. Instead I am trying this in a struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    std::map<int, double>* my_map;

    MyStruct(bool dir)
    {
        if(dir)
        {
            my_map = new std::map<int, double, std::less<int> >;
        }
        else
        {
            my_map = new std::map<int, double, std::greater<int> >;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't working and complains that I am changing the type under the `else` condition. Is there a way around this? The only way I can think of is to write my own comparator and to create an object encapsulating `bool dir` which seems redundant.

Comment: Is it known at compile time whether you want `less` or `greater`? Or only at runtime?

Comment: @JosephMansfield only at runtime unfortunately.

Comment: I think you will have to write your own comparator. However, someone else might have a better idea. But on a sidenote: If you want to write proper c++, encapsulate the map in a `std::unique_ptr` and use (if available in your compiler) `std::make_unique` to create the map. This way you don't have to care about releasing the map in the destructor.

Comment: @Excelcius yea, I am stumped as well. Agreed about the destruction, I have that in there, just put up the example to give a gist of what I am looking for.

Comment: You could use [Boost variant.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: @jrok a variant seems a little heavy-handed for this application.

Comment: @GuyGreer Why you think that?

Comment: @jrok Because then using the variant for anything either requires `get<...>` everytime you want to use it or a static_visitor for each use.  Unless I'm missing something

Comment: @GuyGreer: Your approach adds a conditional branch to every comparison, and there will be a bunch of them for every insert, find, etc. A variant of two maps would do the conditional outside of each map operation, so it would probably be faster. Whether that is worth the "heavy-handedness" depends on the application, of course.

Comment: If you only need it forward or backward, why not just choose a forward or backward iterator type at runtime?

Comment: @Joshua: Why do you `new` the `map` ? Why not do away with the pointer and just put the map by value into `MyStruct` ? In C++, `new` is to keep for *rare* situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` takes the comparison object as a template parameter, so to do what you want you need a type that you can change the behaviour at runtime.

```
    struct MoreOrLess
    {
      bool useLess;
      template <class T, class U>
      bool operator()(const T &t, const U &u) const
      {
        if(useLess) return t < u;
        else return t > u;
      }
    };

    struct MyStruct
    {
        std::map<int, double, MoreOrLess> my_map;

        MyStruct(bool dir) :my_map(MoreOrLess{dir}) {}
    };
```

This way the comparison functor has the same type (for use in `std::map`) regardless of using `std::less` or `std::greater`.

Comment: Might as well do away with the pointer, and initialize the map in the initializer list.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I agree, I just didn't want to change the OP's example more than necessary.

Comment: @GuyGreer I like this solution as well as jrok's. I will try both to see which one is more suitable for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach, although probably not the most efficient:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    typedef std::function<bool(int,int)> Predicate;
    std::map<int,double,Predicate> my_map;

    static Predicate predicateFor(bool dir)
    {
        if (dir) return std::less<int>();
        return std::greater<int>();
    }

    MyStruct(bool dir) : my_map(predicateFor(dir)) { }
};
```